# Light sensor emulation with camera

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I have already programmed the camera with the camera2 API, but when I execute the onCaptureCompleted or onCaptureProgressed method, the values ​​get null except LENS_FOCAl_LENGTH.

```
@Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

        String aperture = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_APERTURE));
        String focal_length = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH));
        String focus_distance = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE));
        String exposure_time = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME));
        String frame_duration = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME));
        String sensitivity = String.valueOf(result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY));

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zj72.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to test on other device. 
According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult) almost all values "Optional - The value for this key may be null on some devices."

But for example LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH that is not null in your case is "This key is available on all devices." So all values depends on device type.